# Filtering data based on match inside JSON

Tags: javascript

The idea is to get the values of the `district` and `ward` keys from the JSON data below based on a `serial_number` entered by the user. Also, when there's a match, depending on where the match was found, the key(`grievance` or `general`) should also get displayed.
For example, if the user input is `0018`, then the data I need to display are :

1. Hooghly as is the value of `district` in the object where the match was made.
2. 8 as is the value of `ward`
3. `general` as is key which holds the array where the match was made.

This here is the JSON

```
[
    {
        "district": "Kolkata",
        "ward_no": [
            {
                "ward": "6",
                "grievance": [
                    {   
                        "serial_number": "0001",
                        "name" : "Mr.A"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0002",
                        "name" : "Mr.B"
                    }
                ],
                "general": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0003",
                        "name" : "Mr.C"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0004",
                        "name" : "Mr.D"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ward": "7",
                "grievance": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0005",
                        "name" : "Mr.E"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0006",
                        "name" : "Mr.F"
                    }
                ],
                "general": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0007",
                        "name" : "Mr.G"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0008",
                        "name" : "Mr.H"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "district": "Hooghly",
        "ward_no": [
            {
                "ward": "8",
                "grievance": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0009",
                        "name" : "Mr.I"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0010",
                        "name" : "Mr.J"
                    }
                ],
                "general": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0011",
                        "name" : "Mr.K"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0012",
                        "name" : "Mr.L"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ward": "9",
                "grievance": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0013",
                        "name" : "Mr.M"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0014",
                        "name" : "Mr.N"
                    }
                ],
                "general": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0015",
                        "name" : "Mr.O"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0018",
                        "name" : "Bruno Fernandes"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is kind of new to me and there's no way I can think of a solution for this. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it also with .find.

```js
const data = [{"district": "Kolkata","ward_no": [{"ward": "6","grievance": [{"serial_number": "0001","name": "Mr.A"},{"serial_number": "0002","name": "Mr.B"}],"general": [{"serial_number": "0003","name": "Mr.C"},{"serial_number": "0004","name": "Mr.D" } ] }, { "ward": "7", "grievance": [{ "serial_number": "0005", "name": "Mr.E" }, { "serial_number": "0006", "name": "Mr.F" } ], "general": [{ "serial_number": "0007", "name": "Mr.G" }, { "serial_number": "0008", "name": "Mr.H" } ] } ] }, { "district": "Hooghly", "ward_no": [{ "ward": "8", "grievance": [{ "serial_number": "0009", "name": "Mr.I" }, { "serial_number": "0010", "name": "Mr.J" } ], "general": [{ "serial_number": "0011", "name": "Mr.K" }, { "serial_number": "0012", "name": "Mr.L" } ] }, { "ward": "9", "grievance": [{ "serial_number": "0013", "name": "Mr.M" }, { "serial_number": "0014", "name": "Mr.N" } ], "general": [{ "serial_number": "0015", "name": "Mr.O" }, { "serial_number": "0018", "name": "Bruno Fernandes" } ] } ] } ]

const findObject = (serial)=>{
    const obj = data.find(el=>JSON.stringify(el.ward_no).includes(serial));
    if(obj){
        const ward = obj.ward_no.find(el=>JSON.stringify(el).includes(serial));
        return {district: obj.district, ward: ward.ward, key: JSON.stringify(ward.grievance).includes(serial)?'grievance': 'general'}
    }else return {}
}

console.log(findObject('0018'))
```

Answer (score 0):

What's needed is like a find(), except one that keeps track of the context within the object where the match is made. [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) will help, since it halts iteration as soon as the closure returns something truthy.

With that, all that's needed is to save the few facts the caller needs once a match is made...

```js
// return false if district does not contain serial number
// if it does, return an object with a few facts about the match
function districtHasSerialNumber(district, serialNumber) {
  let result = {};  // return this on success
  let hasSerialNumber = district.ward_no.some(ward => {
    result.found = ward.general.some(gen => {
      if (gen.serial_number === serialNumber) {
        // save the context
        result.district = district.district; 
        result.ward = ward.ward; 
        result.key = 'general';
        return true;
      } else return false;
    });
    if (!result.found) {
      result.found = ward.grievance.some(gre => {
        if (gre.serial_number === serialNumber) {
          // save the context
          result.district = district.district; 
          result.ward = ward.ward; 
          result.key = 'grievance';
          return true;
        } else return false;
      });
    }
    return result.found;
  });
  return hasSerialNumber ? result : false;
}

// demo
let data = districtData();
let serialNumber = "0018"
let result;
for (let district of data) {
  result = districtHasSerialNumber(district, serialNumber)
  if (result) break;
}
console.log(result);

function districtData() {
  return [{
      "district": "Kolkata",
      "ward_no": [{
          "ward": "6",
          "grievance": [{
              "serial_number": "0001",
              "name": "Mr.A"
            },
            {
              "serial_number": "0002",
              "name": "Mr.B"
            }
          ],
          "general": [{
              "serial_number": "0003",
              "name": "Mr.C"
            },
            {
              "serial_number": "0004",
              "name": "Mr.D"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "ward": "7",
          "grievance": [{
              "serial_number": "0005",
              "name": "Mr.E"
            },
            {
              "serial_number": "0006",
              "name": "Mr.F"
            }
          ],
          "general": [{
              "serial_number": "0007",
              "name": "Mr.G"
            },
            {
              "serial_number": "0008",
              "name": "Mr.H"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "district": "Hooghly",
      "ward_no": [{
          "ward": "8",
          "grievance": [{
              "serial_number": "0009",
              "name": "Mr.I"
            },
            {
              "serial_number": "0010",
              "name": "Mr.J"
            }
          ],
          "general": [{
              "serial_number": "0011",
              "name": "Mr.K"
            },
            {
              "serial_number": "0012",
              "name": "Mr.L"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "ward": "9",
          "grievance": [{
              "serial_number": "0013",
              "name": "Mr.M"
            },
            {
              "serial_number": "0014",
              "name": "Mr.N"
            }
          ],
          "general": [{
              "serial_number": "0015",
              "name": "Mr.O"
            },
            {
              "serial_number": "0018",
              "name": "Bruno Fernandes"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code `reduces array` of districts to the the districts having required `serial_number`.

This will include whole filtered data of the district. `I more than one district with required result is present, or the result is present both in grievance and general, then it will include both.

```js
const obj=[{district:"Kolkata",ward_no:[{ward:"6",grievance:[{serial_number:"0001",name:"Mr.A"},{serial_number:"0002",name:"Mr.B"}],general:[{serial_number:"0003",name:"Mr.C"},{serial_number:"0004",name:"Mr.D"}]},{ward:"7",grievance:[{serial_number:"0005",name:"Mr.E"},{serial_number:"0006",name:"Mr.F"}],general:[{serial_number:"0007",name:"Mr.G"},{serial_number:"0008",name:"Mr.H"}]}]},{district:"Hooghly",ward_no:[{ward:"8",grievance:[{serial_number:"0009",name:"Mr.I"},{serial_number:"0010",name:"Mr.J"}],general:[{serial_number:"0011",name:"Mr.K"},{serial_number:"0012",name:"Mr.L"}]},{ward:"9",grievance:[{serial_number:"0013",name:"Mr.M"},{serial_number:"0014",name:"Mr.N"}],general:[{serial_number:"0015",name:"Mr.O"},{serial_number:"0018",name:"Bruno Fernandes"}]}]}];

let num = "0018"
let district = obj.reduce((districts, district) => {

  /*--Get ward with given serial number--*/
  let ward = district.ward_no.reduce((wards, ward) => { 

    /*--Check in grievance--*/
    let inGrievance = ward.grievance.filter((house) => house.serial_number === num);

    /*--Check in general--*/
    let inGeneral = ward.general.filter((house) => house.serial_number === num);
    //console.log("grienvance & general ", inGrievance, inGeneral);

    /*--If not found in general or grievance, this ward is of no  use so return wards as it is--*/
    if (!inGrievance.length && !inGeneral.length) return wards;
    let finalWard = {
      ward: ward.ward
    };

    /*--If found in grievance, then add it to answer wards--*/
    if (inGrievance.length) finalWard.grievance = inGrievance;
   /*--If found in general, then add it to answer wards--*/
    if (inGeneral.length) finalWard.general = inGeneral;
    //console.log("final Ward ", finalWard);
    return [...wards, finalWard];
  }, []);

  //console.log("Ward", ward)
  /*--If not found in any of wards of district, then it is of no use--*/
  if (!ward || !ward.length) return districts;
  return [...districts, {
    district: district.district,
    ward
  }];
}, [])

console.log("You district is ", district);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to solve with traditional for loop. nested loop is needed to find the value of serial number.

```
const user_serial_number = "0018"
let found = {
  district: "",
  ward: "",
  arrayKey: ""
}

let i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, l = 0
try {
  // loop level 1
  for (i = 0; i < json_.length; i++) {
    const x = json_[i]; // hold district

    // loop inside ward no
    for (j = 0; j < x.ward_no.length; j++) {
      const y = x.ward_no[j]; // hold ward_no

      // loop inside general key
      for (k = 0; k < y.general.length; k++) {
        const z = y.general[k]; // hold general

        if (z.serial_number === user_serial_number) {
          found = {
            district: x.district,
            ward: y.ward,
            arrayKey: "general"
          }
        }

      }

      // loop inside grievance key
      for (l = 0; l < y.grievance.length; l++) {
        const xa = y.grievance[l];

        if (xa.serial_number === user_serial_number) {
          found = {
            district: x.district,
            ward: y.ward,
            arrayKey: "grievance",
          }
        }

      }

    }

  }
  console.log("=========================")
  console.log("found", found)
} catch (error) {
  console.log("error =>", error)
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).